# Trigger in PostgreSQL does not accept default

Tags: postgresql

I have a table "xxx" with a column "req". 
On this column "req" I would like it always to take values ​​automatically generated in the following manner .. column "req" values ​​Ref_0001,  after another insert Ref_0002, Ref_0003 .... ...
I try the first solution thx to @Craig Ringer

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_ref;

CREATE TABLE dossier
        (
        ref TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 'ref' || NEXTVAL('seq_ref'),
        value TEXT
        );
```

If you want zero-padded numbers, use this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_ref;

CREATE TABLE dossier
        (
        ref TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 'ref' || LPAD(NEXTVAL('seq_ref')::TEXT, 10, '0'),
        value TEXT
        );
```

This solution it not works fine with my application program on insert new line ..
but with pgAdmin when I try to insert, the column is empty until I refresh the table .. so I try to work with a trigger.

I finally create a trigger in PostgreSQL, to solve my problem. Generating values for column req of
this form Ref00001, Ref0002 ... but it does not change; it does not work; still empty column:

```
CREATE table test(
id serial primary key,
non varchar(12),
req varchar(12)
  );

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Start_generate() RETURNS trigger AS $emp_stamp$
    BEGIN

      NEW.req := ('ref'::text || lpad((nextval('seq_refcomposant'::regclass))::text, 6, '0'::text));

        return null;
    END;
$emp_stamp$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER Generate_ref AFTER INSERT ON test
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE Start_generate();
```

I don't know why it does not work ... I Add Default to

```
NEW.req := DEFAULT  ('ref'::text || lpad((nextval('seq_refcomposant'::regclass))::text, 6, '0'::text));
```

and there is an error on default!

How can I achieve the effect I want?

Comment: An absolute wild guess (because I didn't understand your question at all): try with returning `NEW` from the procedure, rather than `null`.

Comment: I edit My question ..sory for not understanding :)

Comment: I try also return New it not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a before trigger, and return the row:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Start_generate() RETURNS trigger AS $emp_stamp$
    BEGIN

      NEW.req := ('ref'::text || lpad((nextval('seq_refcomposant'::regclass))::text, 6, '0'::text));

        return NEW;
    END;
$emp_stamp$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER Generate_ref BEFORE INSERT ON test
    FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.req IS NULL)
EXECUTE PROCEDURE Start_generate();
```

Comment: think you :))))))))))))) your are the best (y) @Denis thx for your cooperation it works fine now